# remove elements from 2D numpy array based on proximity

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a ndarray of the following shape:

```
[[5 2][6 2][10 2][10 10]]
```

These are X Y coordinates. How can I iterate over this array and remove all the subsequent elements that are closer to the current element in 2D (Euclidean distance) than an arbitrary threshold number? For example I'd set the distance threshold to 1 and I would get the following array

```
[[5 2][10 2][10 10]]
```

[6 2] would be removed because it's closer than the threshold (1).

real world data:

```
array([[ 25, 478],
   [ 26, 366],
   [ 26, 478],
   [ 27, 183],
   [ 28, 367],
   [ 28, 477],
   [ 29, 477],
   [ 43, 374],
   [ 44, 374],
   [ 45, 374],
   [ 46, 374],
   [ 47, 374],
   [ 47, 375],
   [ 57,  82],
   [ 58, 133],
   [ 60,  25],
   [ 86, 445],
   [ 89, 226],
   [ 89, 227],
   [ 89, 228],
   [ 89, 229],
   [ 89, 230],
   [ 96, 286],
   [105, 404],
   [106, 404],
   [107, 403],
   [108, 403],
   [117, 355],
   [119, 355],
   [121,  43],
   [122,  42],
   [122,  43],
   [122, 127],
   [122, 490],
   [123, 489],
   [123, 490],
   [137, 438],
   [138, 437],
   [151, 229],
   [162, 149],
   [163, 326],
   [188, 465],
   [188, 466],
   [189, 115],
   [189, 116],
   [218, 291],
   [230, 174],
   [230, 175],
   [230, 176],
   [230, 177],
   [231, 173],
   [231, 174],
   [231, 175],
   [231, 176],
   [231, 177],
   [231, 178],
   [240,  33],
   [241,  33],
   [242,  34],
   [249, 118],
   [250, 256],
   [260, 208],
   [260, 209],
   [260, 210],
   [274, 372],
   [277,  39],
   [302, 216],
   [302, 217],
   [302, 218],
   [302, 219],
   [302, 220],
   [302, 221],
   [302, 222],
   [302, 223],
   [315, 325],
   [322, 258],
   [322, 259],
   [341, 172],
   [346, 457],
   [359, 388],
   [360, 389],
   [361, 390],
   [386, 307],
   [392, 372],
   [393, 136],
   [393, 360],
   [393, 374],
   [394, 134],
   [394, 135],
   [394, 136],
   [394, 137],
   [394, 138],
   [394, 139],
   [394, 140],
   [394, 141],
   [394, 142],
   [394, 143],
   [394, 144],
   [409, 266],
   [437, 132],
   [439, 131],
   [467, 100],
   [471, 236],
   [472, 235],
   [474, 234],
   [479, 104]])
```

Comment: Wahts *distance in 2D* ?

Comment: Euclidean distance, sqrt(x*x + y*y).

Comment: So whats that *distance* in your list that `[6 2]` must be removed?

Comment: in this example it could be 1. x(5)y(2) is 1 point away from x(6)y(2)

Comment: Which element is the element that you calculate the Euclidean distance to? The first in that list? The [0,0] element? Any other not shown? Does the element to which you compare always change, so that you are each time only looking at one element and *all* the subsequent elements (that means, element 0 compared to [1:], element 1 compared to [2:]...)

Comment: you would go over the array starting with the first one [5 2], u would remove all the following elements that are closer than 1, so for [5 2] you'd remove [6 2]. Then you would jump to [10 2] and remove all the elements that are closer than 1, but there are no such elements in this array, so you would loop over to [10 10] and since there are again no elements to remove, that would be it

Comment: so for each element you would look through the entire array. but the array is changing because you are removing the elements that are too close to the current one

Comment: That seems like an issue that cannot be implemented efficiently (ie vectorized), because it depends each time on the changes made the last time. Not that you asked for efficiency. Now your last comment actually made this question a whole lot more clear (unambiguous), and you have basically written the algorithm already. Can you show us what *you* have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a list while removing elements from it is a bad practice, because it leads to unforseen effects. For that reason, I think it's more clear to call a function and return a new list from that function.

```
def reduce_tail(l, index, threshold=1):
    elm = l[index]
    mask = np.linalg.norm(elm-l, axis=1) > threshold
    mask[:index+1] = True  #ensure to return the head of the array unchanged
    return l[mask]

def my_reduce(z, threshold=1):
    z = np.array(z)
    index = 0
    while True:
        z = reduce_tail(z, index, threshold)
        index += 1
        if index == z.shape[0]:
            break
    return z.tolist()
```

Demo:

```
>>> z = [[5, 2],[6, 2],[5,1],[10, 2],[10, 10]]
>>> x = [[5, 2],[6, 2],[6,3],[10, 2],[10, 10]]
>>> l = [[5, 2],[6, 2],[10, 2],[10, 10]]
>>> my_reduce(l)
[[5, 2], [10, 2], [10, 10]]
>>> my_reduce(x)
[[5, 2], [6, 3], [10, 2], [10, 10]]
>>> my_reduce(z)
[[5, 2], [10, 2], [10, 10]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.linalg.norm` to check the distance and for get the pairs you can use `zip` function :

```
>>> [i if np.linalg.norm(np.array(i)-np.array(j))==1 else j for i,j in zip(l,l[1:])]
[[5, 2], [10, 2], [10, 10]]
```

Also as a more complete way you can use a recursion function :

```
[[5, 2], [6, 2], [6, 3], [10, 2], [10, 10]]
>>> def a(l):
...      for i,j in zip(l,l[1:]):
...              if np.linalg.norm(np.array(i)-np.array(j))==1 :
...                   l.remove(j)
...                   print l
...                   return a(l)
...      return l
... 
>>> a(l)
[[5, 2], [6, 3], [10, 2], [10, 10]]
```

Comment: Now try with `l = [[5, 2],[6, 2],[6,3],[10, 2],[10, 10]]` and see if it meets the requirements.

Comment: @OliverW. the result is `[[5, 2], [6, 2], [10, 2], [10, 10]]` but it all based on the condition on list comprehension!

Comment: yes, but [6,2] shouldn't be present. That's because throughout each iteration, the list should 've changed which your current approach doesn't do.

Comment: @Kasra so in the oliver's example the resulting array should be [[5, 2],[6,3],[10, 2],[10, 10]] with the distance variable set to 1

Comment: Sorry, Kasra, still incorrect. Try `z = [[5, 2],[6, 2],[5,1],[10, 2],[10, 10]]`.

Comment: I tested it with my data. So it removes some points, but it leaves others. I added the real array to the question description so u can see for yourself. Specifically, if you set the threshold < 50 then [25,478] and [26,478] will be still present, even though [26,478] should have been removed...